# Directly login to facebook with access token

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

How can we directly login to facebook with access token or if we have username and password.

Is there any script or Graph API method which allows to login directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the access token you're referring to is the OAuth access token.  [OAuth's spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849) states:

```
Unlike the resource owner credentials, tokens can be issued with a restricted scope...
```

So having an access token doesn't give you full access to the account, which is why you can't use it to log in.

As for the user name and password, that's exactly what you need in order to log in.  To access the account dynamically, you need an HTTP client, such as [RestClient](https://github.com/adamwiggins/rest-client) (for Ruby) or [HttpClient](http://scripts.incutio.com/httpclient/) (for PHP) to send the request and receive the response.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the OAuth's specs and yes, i am referring to the OAuth access token. So it seems that using token we can't directly login. 
I have my token with me and all the info stored in db. How can i access my facebook profile without login or entering the username and password. Can we form some link ?

Comment: You need to send HTTP requests to facebook in the formats described in their [API documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/apis/).  The documentation should also describe with URL requests of different types should go to.  You can send the requests using one of the HTTP clients I described above.

Comment: If you're working with Ruby, [see this example I wrote](https://github.com/betesh/fresh-auth).  It's not for facebook, but it should give you a good template to work off of.  Or you can just google for facebook API examples--you might find that there are plenty of libraries that can make this stuff very easy.